# Force repaint after button click

Tags: java, swing, events, scala

consider this piece of scala swing code

```
detail.reactions += {
  case ButtonClicked(but) =>
    detail.contents += new Label(but.text)
    detail.background = new java.awt.Color(0,255,0)
}
```

the `detail` is of `FlowPanel` type.
When the button is clicked, the color is instantly repainted, but the `Label` is not. It gets visible as I click the area. How can I force the `detail` to repaint its contents after a click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, the answer would normally be to call `repaint()`.  Did you try `detail.repaint()`?

Comment: solved by calling repaint but not in detail, but in component 2 levels above it.