# JDialog repaint after JList modification

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a JDialog dlg, created by a JFrame frm, that contains a JList list.
When I modify the list (through the ListModel), the list itself is repainted but not the JDialog.
This means that, if I delete a line, the list remains with an empty line while if I add a line, this new line won't be shown (because there is no space in the dialog) until I manually force repainting of dlg (doubleclicking in frm).

Following advices in this post :
[How to make repaint for JDialog in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105933/how-to-make-repaint-for-jdialog-in-swing)

and in this post:
[Force repaint after button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495852/force-repaint-after-button-click)

I tried to call, from my controller class (which is where updates to list are made), the following line:

```
SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(dlg).repaint();
```

but it didn't work.
I also tried:

```
dlg.repaint();
```

No luck either...

Any clue?
Thank you very much.

EDIT:
The organization of my classes is as follows:
a controller class that contains a reference to the main JFrame, frm.
I also extended JDialog into MyDialog, which contains a JList.
When a doubleclick on frm is detected, I show the instance of MyDialog (or create, if it is the first time I show it) and the JList is filled with the data passed to the DefaultListModel. MyDialog is painted so that the list has only the space that it needs.
Now, when a specific event is detected by the controller, I get the specific MyDialog, get the ListModel from JList and update it. Here the JList is indeed updated, but Dialog remains the same.
I use a code like this:

```
MyDialog dlg = group.getDlg();
if(dlg != null){
    DefaultListModel listModel = ((DefaultListModel) dlg.getMyJList().getModel());
    listModel.addElement(idStock);
    SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(dlg).repaint();
}
```

This doesn't repaint dlg. 
I also tried:

```
SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(dlg.getMyJList()).repaint();
```

but it doesn't work.

I checked with the debugger that the lines are actually executed.

I don't have much more code to show, really.....

Comment: Can you post a short sample code that accurately depicts the problem ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: As stated, post some code. Try also a revalidate() and, of course, use the debugger to make sure you enter the piece of code where you call the repaint / revalidate method.

Comment: should I try the revalidate() "instead of" or "before" the repaint?

Comment: Have you put your JList inside a JScrollPane? If not, that's what you should do. The problem would be more obvious if you posted code,as asked alread three times.

Comment: I put it into a JScrollPane and it solved the problem! (actually, it avoided it, but it's the same for me!) Thnx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you going wrong way, define `DefaultListModel` that accesible throught all Java methods and Classes, this `Model` would holds your `Objects`, then put `JList` to the `JDialog` or `JOptionPane`, for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

// based on @trashgod code
/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759131 */
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667719/jdialog-repaint-after-jlist-modification

public class ListDialog {

    private static final int N = 12;
    private JDialog dlg = new JDialog();
    private DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    private JList list = new JList(model);
    private JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(list);
    private int count;

    public ListDialog() {
        list.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                append();
                if (count <= N) {
                    list.setVisibleRowCount(count);
                    dlg.pack();
                }
            }
        }));
        panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Remove") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int itemNo = list.getSelectedIndex();
                if (itemNo > -1) {
                    removeActionPerformed(e, itemNo);
                }
            }
        }));
        for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i++) {
            this.append();
        }
        list.setVisibleRowCount(N - 2);
        dlg.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        dlg.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        dlg.pack();
        dlg.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dlg.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void removeActionPerformed(ActionEvent e, int itemNo) {
        System.out.println("made_list's model: " + list.getModel());
        System.out.println("Model from a fresh JList: " + new JList().getModel());
        model = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
        if (model.size() > 0) {
            if (itemNo > -1) {
                model.remove(itemNo);
            }
        }
    }

    private void append() {
        model.addElement("String " + String.valueOf(++count));
        list.ensureIndexIsVisible(count - 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] a_args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ListDialog pd = new ListDialog();
            }
        });
    }
}
```